# MVC3 Display text using Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display a text on the view from the database.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<HUI.Models.Events>>" %>
```

Tried to use the following but did not work

```
 <%:Model.First().Name.ToString();%>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your object HUI.Models.Events have a Name event ? and try something like <div> <%=Model.First().Name.ToString();%></div>

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got the following error:Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the semicolon after ToString not giving you a compilation error?

If **Name** property is of type string then this should simply suffice:

> <%:Model.First().Name %>

Can you send the error details if any, if this suggestion doesn't work?

Also - error details would help us too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. 
First, you have the semi-colon at the end as others mentioned.

Secondly, you have:

```
IEnumerable<HUI.Models.Events>
```

Are you sure you don't want:

```
IEnumerable<HUI.Models.Event>
```

(Event - not Events)?